# Adding a game of snake to a loading screen?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This is a bit of an odd request, but I have a photo website and the homepage takes a while (10 seconds) to fully load all of the images, which appear in a fullscreen slideshow.

Rather than having the user wait during that time, I'd like to add a game of snake to the homepage until all of the images have loaded (a la [Youtube loading screen](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/07/play-snake-in-youtubes-player.html)), then close the game and start the slideshow as usual.

I don't have much experience with css, php, or javascript, but I'm mainly asking because I want to know how difficult of a task this would be if I wanted to commission, say, a freelancer to do it or something, and if I'm asking too much with this.

Comment: Ten seconds isn't long enough to play a game of Snake. But anyway, a simple Snake implementation is certainly possible, and shouldn't take all that many lines of JavaScript so I would think it could load reasonably quickly - but adding more code that has to load up front to entertain the user when they're already waiting for other things to load...?

Comment: My thoughts on this...  instead of having a game (though I like the way you're thinking here), I would recommend having someone look in to loading the photos via AJAX instead of on site load.   This would let your site load almost instantly, and then the photos can load in the background.   From the user experience, they would think everything was loaded, as the pictures would be downloaded before they viewed them.   But most of the "heavy lifting" would happen after the user was at the site already.   I think it would give a much better user experience.